# Linux webserver load balance howto

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, load-balancing

I need to deliver a lot of HTTP content (Lets say it simple - a Big storage with HTTTP Access - Similar to AWS S3)
The Bandwith needed for this excedds the Bandwith of one Server (We get 200MBit each Server and the question is not to change this)
For out Prog we need 1Gbit that woudl mean 5 Servers. 
When I connect them togeter with mod_proxy then I have one Server in front which only has 200MBit. So thats not the right way.

But these Servers must be accassible from the Web with one Domain Name. Is there a possibillity to so that? Example: One gets the HTTP Request, but the Resonse comes from a different Server?
DNS Round Robin?
Different Idea?

Thanx

Comment: What is the write/read ratio?

Answer (score 0):

If the outbound network traffic is not CPU limited, you can use this open source Linux Network Balancer

http://lnlb.sourceforge.net/

The inbound network speed will remain at 200MBit, but with five nodes the maximum outbound limit is 5*200MBit.

Comment: A proxy will only help if I need to balance CPU Ressources. I need to combine Network ressources. Each machine has 200MBit. I need a virtual Machine with 1GBit (made up by 5 machines)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people condemn round robin DNS, perhaps assuming that it will take a full TCP timeout to detect all failed node which is simply not the case. Its a simple way to solve the performance problem and improves availability a lot. This also helps to solve the potential bottleneck of your lan without having to go to 10gbit Ethernet which would be a requirement between a router and a load balancer for the rate of traffic you describe.

There may be scope for getting more throughput from your servers and hence only needing 3 or 4 servers rather than 5. But that's a very different question.